# feeding Angular Material Table from rest data - ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular. Right now I'm developing a prototype in Angular (7).
The prototype shall load data using rest from an external page (AZURE). I managed to setup the request and I can see the data provided in the console but I have no idea how to initialize the Material table to use the responded data to build the table and I couldn't find any example on the internet for Angular version 7.

I'm looking for a code example once I see it I will manage to understand.

This is the JSON datafrom the response (I cut it in order to make it fit into the post), My ts files are the ones you get when you run:

ng generate @angular/material:material-table --name=accountlist

```
====accountlist.component.html====
 <div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" [dataSource]="accounts.data.Documents" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="ID">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.ID}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

        <!-- City Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="City">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>City</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.City}}</td>
          </ng-container>

              <!-- Country Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Country">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Country</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.Country}}</td>
      </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="accounts.data.Documents.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="50"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>

====accountlist.comoponent.ts====
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { AccountlistDataSource } from './accountlist-datasource';
import { AzureService } from './../_services/azure.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accountlist',
  templateUrl: './accountlist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accountlist.component.css']
})
export class AccountlistComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource: AccountlistDataSource;
  public accounts: any;

  constructor(private azureService: AzureService) {

  }

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['ID', 'Name', 'City', 'Country'];

  readAccountsAzure(): void {
    this.azureService.getAccountsAzure()
      .subscribe(
        accounts => {
          this.accounts = accounts;
          console.log(this.accounts.Documents);
        }
      );
  }

  RenderDataTable() {
    this.azureService.getAccountsAzure()
      .subscribe(
      res => {
        this.accounts = new AccountlistDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort);
        this.accounts.data = res as Account[];
        console.log(this.accounts);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('There was an error while retrieving data !!!' + error);
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.RenderDataTable();
   // this.accounts = new AccountlistDataSource(this.paginator, this.sort);
  }
}


====accountlist-datasource.ts====
import { AzureService } from './../_services/azure.service';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';

// TODO: Replace this with your own data model type
export interface AccountlistItem {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

// TODO: replace this with real data from your application
const EXAMPLE_DATA: AccountlistItem[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Lithium'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Beryllium'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Boron'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Carbon'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Nitrogen'},
  {id: 8, name: 'Oxygen'},
  {id: 9, name: 'Fluorine'},
  {id: 10, name: 'Neon'},
  {id: 11, name: 'Sodium'},
  {id: 12, name: 'Magnesium'},
  {id: 13, name: 'Aluminum'},
  {id: 14, name: 'Silicon'},
  {id: 15, name: 'Phosphorus'},
  {id: 16, name: 'Sulfur'},
  {id: 17, name: 'Chlorine'},
  {id: 18, name: 'Argon'},
  {id: 19, name: 'Potassium'},
  {id: 20, name: 'Calcium'},
];

/**
 * Data source for the Accountlist view. This class should
 * encapsulate all logic for fetching and manipulating the displayed data
 * (including sorting, pagination, and filtering).
 */
export class AccountlistDataSource extends DataSource<AccountlistItem> {
  // data: AccountlistItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;
data: AccountlistItem[];

  constructor(private paginator: MatPaginator, private sort: MatSort) {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<AccountlistItem[]> {
    // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
    // stream for the data-table to consume.
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    // Set the paginator's length
    this.paginator.length = this.data.length;

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the table is being destroyed. Use this function, to clean up
   * any open connections or free any held resources that were set up during connect.
   */
  disconnect() {}

  /**
   * Paginate the data (client-side). If you're using server-side pagination,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getPagedData(data: AccountlistItem[]) {
    const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  /**
   * Sort the data (client-side). If you're using server-side sorting,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getSortedData(data: AccountlistItem[]) {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'id': return compare(+a.id, +b.id, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

/** Simple sort comparator for example ID/Name columns (for client-side sorting). */
function compare(a, b, isAsc) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}


====JSON RESPONSE====
 {  
   "_rid":"R-UdANZutGw=",
   "Documents":[  
      {  
         "id":"c5826db5-d68b-4be8-84ed-c4cc3c15cd5a",
         "_rid":"R-UdANZutGwJAAAAAAAAAA==",
         "_self":"dbs\/R-UdAA==\/colls\/R-UdANZutGw=\/docs\/R-UdANZutGwJAAAAAAAAAA==\/",
         "_etag":"\"06000f28-0000-0c00-0000-5c34d2830000\"",
         "Account Number":"232342-555445",
         "Country":"Germany",
         "Created Date":"01/10/2018",
         "Currency":"US Dollar",
         "ID":"8adc8f99661fc13b01662f31eeb413dc",
         "Name":"85255-1545445",
         "SHS_SAP_SOLD_TO":"US_0000001234",
         "Status":"Active",
         "Address 1":"",
         "Address 2":"",
         "City":"",
         "County":"",
         "Postal Code":"",
         "State/Province":"",
         "_attachments":"attachments\/",
         "_ts":1546965635
      },
      {  
         "id":"1f990cdf-d64c-49d4-b6bc-4fdc91462d2c",
         "_rid":"R-UdANZutGwvAQAAAAAAAA==",
         "_self":"dbs\/R-UdAA==\/colls\/R-UdANZutGw=\/docs\/R-UdANZutGwvAQAAAAAAAA==\/",
         "_etag":"\"06003529-0000-0c00-0000-5c34d2830000\"",
         "Account Number":"90164412-100532",
         "Country":"Germany",
         "Created Date":"01/10/2018",
         "Currency":"US Dollar",
         "ID":"8adce421661fcddc01662f3263836dfb",
         "Name":"15151-45100532",
         "SHS_SAP_SOLD_TO":"US_0000001234",
         "Status":"Active",
         "Address 1":"",
         "Address 2":"",
         "City":"",
         "County":"",
         "Postal Code":"",
         "State/Province":"",
         "_attachments":"attachments\/",
         "_ts":1546965635
      },
      {  
         "id":"185e8238-2287-4989-b7f1-d69ffa4f65fe",
         "_rid":"R-UdANZutGwwAQAAAAAAAA==",
         "_self":"dbs\/R-UdAA==\/colls\/R-UdANZutGw=\/docs\/R-UdANZutGwwAQAAAAAAAA==\/",
         "_etag":"\"06003629-0000-0c00-0000-5c34d2830000\"",
         "Account Number":"3432423-324234",
         "Country":"Germany",
         "Created Date":"01/10/2018",
         "Currency":"US Dollar",
         "ID":"8adce421661fcddc01662f3242d86dda",
         "Name":"23432423-324234",
         "SHS_SAP_SOLD_TO":"US_0000001234",
         "Status":"Active",
         "Address 1":"",
         "Address 2":"",
         "City":"",
         "County":"",
         "Postal Code":"",
         "State/Province":"",
         "_attachments":"attachments\/",
         "_ts":1546965635
      },
      {  
         "id":"7894ab52-9d3d-498d-a162-c9b57702c650",
         "_rid":"R-UdANZutGwxAQAAAAAAAA==",
         "_self":"dbs\/R-UdAA==\/colls\/R-UdANZutGw=\/docs\/R-UdANZutGwxAQAAAAAAAA==\/",
         "_etag":"\"06003729-0000-0c00-0000-5c34d2830000\"",
         "Account Number":"234234-234234",
         "Country":"Germany",
         "Created Date":"01/10/2018",
         "Currency":"US Dollar",
         "ID":"8adce421661fcddc01662f323f406dd6",
         "Name":"234234-234234",
         "SHS_SAP_SOLD_TO":"US_0000001234",
         "Status":"Active",
      },
      {  
         "id":"f274b1e9-7bac-48e8-8931-e98b7e8be046",
         "_rid":"R-UdANZutGzvAwAAAAAAAA==",
         "_self":"dbs\/R-UdAA==\/colls\/R-UdANZutGw=\/docs\/R-UdANZutGzvAwAAAAAAAA==\/",
         "_etag":"\"0600f52b-0000-0c00-0000-5c34d2890000\"",
         "Account Number":"324234-23423",
         "Country":"Germany",
         "Created Date":"01/10/2018",
         "Currency":"US Dollar",
         "ID":"8adc8f99661fc13b01662f34da211779",
         "Name":"Default Account",
         "SHS_SAP_SOLD_TO":"US_0000001234",
         "Status":"Active",
         "Address 1":"",
         "Address 2":"",
         "City":"",
         "County":"",
         "Postal Code":"",
         "State/Province":"",
         "_attachments":"attachments\/",
         "_ts":1546965641
      },
      {  
         "id":"415ff345-5ecd-4bfd-b20b-fd8cc7186744",
         "_rid":"R-UdANZutGzwAwAAAAAAAA==",
         "_self":"dbs\/R-UdAA==\/colls\/R-UdANZutGw=\/docs\/R-UdANZutGzwAwAAAAAAAA==\/",
         "_etag":"\"0600f62b-0000-0c00-0000-5c34d2890000\"",
         "Account Number":"324234-234234",
         "Country":"Germany",
         "Created Date":"01/10/2018",
         "Currency":"US Dollar",
         "ID":"8adc8f99661fc13b01662f34cc801765",
         "Name":"324234234",
         "SHS_SAP_SOLD_TO":"US_0000001234",
         "Status":"Active",
         "Address 1":"",
         "Address 2":"",
         "City":"",
         "County":"",
         "Postal Code":"",
         "State/Province":"",
         "_attachments":"attachments\/",
         "_ts":1546965641
      }
   ],
   "_count":1000
}
```

the console log i sindicating that there is an error in the HTML file on line 16:
AccountlistComponent.html:16 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

but I think the issue is actually related to the fact that the data might not be loaded properly

appreciate your support :-)

Comment: Check out [this](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you it cannot read `data` from `undefined`. Which means, looking at your HTML code, that `[length]="dataSource.data.length"` fails, because `dataSource` is not intialized.

The whole point of the `length` is to be a fixed value, otherwise it will always be on one page. So just put `length="50"` or whatever. Or if you want to stick with the length for whatever reason, you probably want `[length]="accounts.length"` instead.

**Before you edited & specified your issue**:
You can find all sorts of examples with associated code in the [official Angular documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

You have the data, so you just have to correctly setup the variables in your component code, with a correct `MatTableDataSource` member.

Comment: Hi Mic,

thanks for that - i changed as you suggested. The Console log shows now:

ERROR Error: Could not find column with id "id".

Once again: There is no example how to change the datasource in the documentation

Comment: As the error message suggests, you want to display column `id` (in your array variable) but you did not define it. Indeed, you define a column `Id`. Remove the capital `I` and put a `i` and you should be ok.

Comment: Hi Mic,
once again thank you very much. The data is now displayed (I updated my Code). I'm still getting an error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

and pagination nor sorting is working. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Getting the feeling that I owe you a beer ... or two

Comment: You'd have to open a new question at that point, because your code has probably changed quite a bit and it is not possible to know from there :) On a sidenote, my post answers your question, so you should upvote and accept it as an answer. Then, you open another question. You will discover that Stack Overflow works this way to ensure maximum reusability for people googling around and finding their issue resolved. It is not reusable if several subquestions are inside a SO post. Thanks! https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work